# How do I convert a javascript array to a 'name' in the name/value pair of a JSON row?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax, json

For example I have this dynamic array which can be of any length but i am given two values of this array.

```
var arrName = ["firstName","lastName"];
```

And i have to make a json variable with exact given values for this dynamic array. Here are my approaches

Method 1: Error Unexpected type '['

```
var jsonValues = {arrName[0] : "Mark", arrName[1]: "Collins"}
```

Method 2: Works but it doesn't display the json contents when typing 'jsonValues' in the console, instead i get an Array type. I am not sure if this is acceptable because i want to JSON.stringify it and pass it via ajax to the php server.

```
var jsonValues = [{}];
jsonValues[arrName[0]] = "Jeffrey";
jsonValues[arrName[1]] = "Douglas";
```

Comment: you're declaring jsonValues to be an array (`[]`),w hich contains an empty object (`{}`) at the array's 0-index. But then you start treating it like it's an object, assigning string keys. You should just start it off properly `jsonValues = {}` as an object to begin with.

Comment: preferrably use push command. give a sample of your dynamic array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want

```
var jsonValues = {};
jsonValues[arrName[0]] = "Jeffrey";
jsonValues[arrName[1]] = "Douglas";
```

For a more generic version, see the [`object`](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-66) function in Underscore.

In ES6, which isn't yet supported in most browsers, there's also a syntax that does what you initially expected:

```
var jsonValues = {
  [arrName[0]]: "Jeffrey",
  [arrName[1]]: "Douglas",
};
```

See [MDN Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names)

Comment: Thanks can't believe its just simple